# How to add JAX-RS to an existing project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am using Java EE, Java 1.7, glassfish 3 and Eclipse Indigo. I have an existing web project that I built from this tutorial: http://www.tech-juice.org/2012/05/13/hello-world-with-jsf-2-0-glassfish-3-maven-svn-and-eclipse/#comment-10560.  Now, I want to add RESTful web services to the project.  I go to Project -> properties, Project Facets and check JAX-RS. I then click the link that says "Further configuration needed". I give a servlet class name. I am now told that "At least one user library must be selected."

What does this mean?

I have looked, but, not seen a tutorial on adding JAX-RS to an existing project.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling implementation library selection should just work.  I believe the library configuration item exists in case you do not want to use the default implementation.

[image]

Comment: That did indeed work. However, adding RESTful services was easier than that. I followed the recipe here: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/